Generic `NamedTuple`
I work with a set of NamedTuple which share two common attributes (key and value), such as:
CompanyIdentifier = NamedTuple("CompanyIdentifier", [
    ("key", str), ("value": str), ("some", str), ("other", str), ("fields", str)])

PeopleIdentifier = NamedTuple("PeopleIdentifier", [
    ("key", str), ("value": str), ("yet", str), ("another", str), ("field", str)])

WhateverIdentifier = NamedTuple("WhateverIdentifier", [
    ("key", str), ("value": str)])

I don't have control over of all these possible NamedTuple, the user of the library is free to create his own, etc.
Now I have created a number of functions to manipulate these classes, let's consider a dummy example:
def print_identifier(i: ???):
    print(i.key)
    print(i.value)

I know that print_identifier can work on any NamedTuple that has a key and value field, but I struggle to express that to the type hint system.
I tried creating some kind of least common denominator idenfitier NamedTuple such as:
AnyIdentifier = NamedTuple("AnyIdentifier", [("key", str), ("value": str)])

But when I try to provide specific real identifiers, mypy and pyright will complain that the real identifiers are not compatible with AnyIdentifier:
from typing import NamedTuple

CompanyIdentifier = NamedTuple(
    "CompanyIdentifier",
    [
        ("key", str),
        ("value", str),
        ("some", str),
        ("other", str),
        ("field", str),
    ],
)

AnyIdentifier = NamedTuple(
    "AnyIdentifier",
    [
        ("key", str),
        ("value", str),
    ],
)


def func(identifier: AnyIdentifier):
    print(identifier.key)
    print(identifier.value)


ci = CompanyIdentifier(key="K", value="V", some="S", other="O", field="F")
gi = AnyIdentifier(key="K", value="V")

func(gi)
func(ci) # <- Error

Argument of type "CompanyIdentifier" cannot be assigned to parameter "identifier" of type "AnyIdentifier" of function "func".
    "CompanyIdentifier" is incompatible with "AnyIdentifier".


@mehdiahmadi indeed, let me fix this

This question is similar to: Type hint for an object that has a given attribute?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@InSync That solution wouldn't work here; there are subtleties for the case of a NamedTuple.

This kind of use case is what protocols, the Python equivalent of an interface, are for. Protocols are a form of structural typing, which the Python Typing Team describes as such:

A structural type (see e.g. Protocols, TypedDict) defines a set of values not by their __class__, but by their properties (e.g. attributes, methods, dictionary key/value types).

To create a protocol, you need to subclass typing.Protocol and give it some methods. Then, if you type hint an object as that subclass, static type checkers will assume that every method defined in the protocol is also available in the object.
This answer provides a good overview of protocols in general, but you'll run into issues in your specific use case because the attributes you're specifying are immutable. To avoid that problem, you should also use the @property decorator to define each of your instance variables as immutable.
You should also define an overloaded version of __getitem__ to support tuple-like indexing and slicing (kudos to @dROOOze for this one), and you should inherit from typing.Iterable to support unpacking.
import typing

class AnyIdentifier(typing.Protocol, typing.Iterable):
    @property
    def key(self) -> str: ...
    @property
    def value(self) -> str: ...

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, item: typing.Literal[0, 1], /) -> str: ...
    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, item: slice, /) -> tuple[str, ...]: ...

# =====TEST CLASSES=====

GoodIdentifier = typing.NamedTuple(
    "GoodIdentifier",
    [
        ("key", str),
        ("value", str),
    ],
)
BadIdentifier = typing.NamedTuple(
    "BadIdentifier",
    [
        ("key", str),
        ("type", str),
    ],
)
good = GoodIdentifier("this is the key", "this is the value")
bad = BadIdentifier("this is the key", "this is the type")

# =====TEST FUNCTIONS=====

def func(identifier: AnyIdentifier):
    print(identifier.key)
    print(identifier.value)
def funcWithIndices(identifier: AnyIdentifier):
    print(identifier[0])
    print(identifier[1])
def funcWithSlicing(identifier: AnyIdentifier):
    print(identifier[:]) 
def funcWithUnpacking(identifier: AnyIdentifier):
    key, value = identifier
    print(key)
    print(value)

# =====TESTS=====

func(good)
funcWithIndices(good)
funcWithSlicing(good)
funcWithUnpacking(good)

func(bad)
funcWithIndices(bad)
funcWithSlicing(bad)
funcWithUnpacking(bad)

namedtuples.py:50: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "BadIdentifier"; expected "AnyIdentifier"  [arg-type]
namedtuples.py:50: note: "BadIdentifier" is missing following "AnyIdentifier" protocol member:
namedtuples.py:50: note:     value
namedtuples.py:51: error: Argument 1 to "funcWithIndices" has incompatible type "BadIdentifier"; expected "AnyIdentifier"  [arg-type]
namedtuples.py:51: note: "BadIdentifier" is missing following "AnyIdentifier" protocol member:
namedtuples.py:51: note:     value
namedtuples.py:52: error: Argument 1 to "funcWithSlicing" has incompatible type "BadIdentifier"; expected "AnyIdentifier"  [arg-type]
namedtuples.py:52: note: "BadIdentifier" is missing following "AnyIdentifier" protocol member:
namedtuples.py:52: note:     value
namedtuples.py:53: error: Argument 1 to "funcWithUnpacking" has incompatible type "BadIdentifier"; expected "AnyIdentifier"  [arg-type]
namedtuples.py:53: note: "BadIdentifier" is missing following "AnyIdentifier" protocol member:
namedtuples.py:53: note:     value


NamedTuple also allows index access, so they should also implement the @overloaded __getitem__(self, item: typing.Literal[0, 1], /) -> str: ... on the protocol.
